# How can i protect against this bypass?

Tags: c++, api, mouse, hook

I have it to protect against bots called by mouse. (if click is by a human or not).

I have it to protect:
http://pastebin.com/SfebsEPj

But some peoples did a bypass:
http://pastebin.com/HK9CekzZ

Anyone have an idea?

Code:

```
HHOOK MouseHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        if(wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *info=(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;     
            if((info->flags & LLMHF_INJECTED) == LLMHF_INJECTED)
            {
                ExitProcess(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
}


void AntiShotbotLogger()
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, hInstance, NULL );
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
```

Bypass:

```
HHOOK MouseHook;


LRESULT CALLBACK ReplaceMousehook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && (wParam  == WM_RBUTTONDOWN || wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN))
    {
        reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam)->flags = 0;
        std::cout << "Injection bypassed!" << std::endl;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
}


void ShotbotBypassExample()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0)&1)
        {
            std::cout << "Sending input now." << std::endl;
            INPUT input[2];
            input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;    
            input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }


        Sleep(1);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread keybind(ShotbotBypassExample);
    keybind.joinable();


    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_MOUSE_LL, ReplaceMousehook, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL );
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: paste a small, self-contained example in the question. I can't be bothered to open untrusted external links.

Comment: _'I need urgently'_ I removed that, for being a primary downvote attractor ...

Comment: @H2CO3 trust, it is pastebin.

Comment: Both of those short pieces of code could easily be pasted into the question here.  Links to external sites go stale leaving the question and any possible answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: @user3018746 _'trust, it is pastebin'_ That's not the point! You should show reasonable code samples **here**, that fit to reproduce the problem or support to illustrate detailed explanations of your particular problems!!

Comment: nobody will help me? :/ talked so much ..

Comment: @user3018746 At least I have retracted my close-/downvote ... But that's the hard point with asking questions here: Either get it right at the 1st hit,- matching all the forum rules -, or get it right after being downvoted already (by editing as you did) and hope that down-/close voters come back to revise their decisions. (**Note:** You can delete your question, and ask a, - hopefully better worded -, new one)

Comment: You cannot do it, because a smart hacker will just write a kernel driver and then all your checks are useless.

Answer (score 0):

Install your **own** hook, **don't** call `CallNextHookEx`. Their hook won't be called then (if it's older).

Furthermore, when you install your hook, check your process for loaded DLL's. Any DLL loaded later may contain a hook which overrides your hook.

Comment: How can i install other hook without calling CallNextHookEx?